# Android Connect Exception

Tags: android, url, connection

i get a strange error message when i try to start an url connection.
here´s the log output:

```
     E/admarvelservice( 2366): postString: &site_id=14488&partner_id=ef8a30b841b36346& timeout=5000&version=1.5&language=java&format=android&sdk_version=2.1.3&sdk_version_date=2011-08-08&device_model=Nexus+S&device_name=GRJ22&get_cached_ads=true&device_systemversion=2.3.5&resolution_width=480&max_image_width=480&resolution_height=800&max_image_height=800&device_os=Android&target_params=appv%3D%3ES%7C%7Cla%3D%3Ede%7C%7Cco%3D%3EAT%7C%7Cscreenorient%3D%3Ep%7C%7Cappvn%3D%3E3.4.0%252F%7C%7Cosv%3D%3E2.3.5

     D/admarvelservice( 2366): Error: java.net.ConnectException: ads.admarvel.com/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused
```

anybody an idea whats the problem here?
thanks.

EDIT: how i connect:

```
URL myURL;
try {
    myURL = new URL(_url);
    m_ucon = myURL.openConnection();
    m_ucon.setConnectTimeout(8000);

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
```

}

funny thing is that the connection is working, but every second my logcat shouts the errormessage shown above.

Comment: Are you able to hit the URL `127.0.0.1:80` outside of your Android app? I hope its running and not blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has nothing to do with your application.
The exception comes from an Advertising Service (admarvelservice).

Answer (score 1):

You are using an adblocker app and you have Shazam installed.  Just either get the paid version of Shazam, remove ad blocker or just ignore the error.

Answer (score 0):

You must set uses permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this first in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Localhost ip address is: `127.0.0.1` so u can check by this too.

try with this http connection:

```
public SomeClass {
    HTTTPUrlConnection conn = new HTTPUrlConnection(...);
    SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();

    private SomeClass() {}
    public static getInstance() {
       return instance;
    }
}
```

you should try `Singleton pattern` for request response.

Answer (score 0):

For my experience

> Connection Refused

is caused by :

a|- You don´t have access because probably you are under a Proxy and you need credentials to establish a connection.

b|- You need to add the persmission for connection inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```